# Spellcheck only replaces first word in TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, spell-checking

I know I have seen this problem before somewhere, but I'm not sure if there was an answer at the time.  I'm trying to add SpellCheck to a `TextBox` in WPF, .NET 4.0.  It works fine in terms of finding and marking the incorrect words, and will replace the first word in the `TextBox` if it's incorrect.  Anything past word one though, and it just moves the carat to the start of the `TextBox` without changing anything?  As I said I saw this somewhere about 6-9 months ago, but now everything I come up with in google deals with alternate languages (I'm staying strictly in English for now). I've included the event methods and styling XAML only for completeness, I don't think the issue lies there.

**XAML:**

```
<MultiBox:MultiBox Name="callNotes" Grid.Column="1" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="2,5,15,20" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AcceptsReturn="True" FontWeight="Bold" GotFocus="callNotes_GotFocus" SelectAllOnGotFocus="False" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" xml:lang="en-US" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" TextChanged="callNotes_TextChanged" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />

<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MyNamespace:MultiBox}">
    <Setter Property="CharacterCasing" Value="Upper" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="23" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="SelectAllOnGotFocus" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
</Style>
```

**Code:**

```
private void callNotes_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    callNotes.Text.ToUpper();
    lineCountOne.Content = ((callNotes.Text.Length / 78) + 1);
}

private void callNotes_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    callNotes.CaretIndex = callNotes.Text.Length;
}
```

Comment: Yes it is.  I completely forgot about that actually, but it inherits from the TextBox class.  It's main purpose is for restricting characters entered and formatting the input (phone #'s, dollar amounts, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to see your code which attempts to correct the errors. Here's simple code which loops through all the detected errors and accepts the first suggestion. If you only want to fix particular errors, you'll need to skip to the particular error you're interested in by getting the error at a certain index.

```
        int ndx;
        while ((ndx = callNotes.GetNextSpellingErrorCharacterIndex(0, LogicalDirection.Forward)) != -1) 
        {
            var err = callNotes.GetSpellingError(ndx);
            foreach (String sugg in err.Suggestions)
            {
                err.Correct(sugg);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

After trying jschroedl's suggestion and still having no luck (although I do know that his answer *should* have been correct), I started playing with every possible setting I could think of, even to the point of creating a completely new WPF project with a single, `Spellcheck`-enabled `TextBox` just to make sure it wasn't something with the Visual Studio/.NET installation itself.  Turns out it wasn't, it was something I had done months ago to ensure that selecting any given `TextBox` through the program would result in the `SelectAll()` method being triggered.  Once I screened out this particular `TextBox` from that bit of code, all works great.  Again, thanks to jschroedl, I know there is no way he could have known this.  The offending code is below, in case anybody comes across a similar issue.

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TextBox), UIElement.GotKeyboardFocusEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(SelectAllText), true);

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }

    protected static void SelectAllText(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = e.OriginalSource as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null && textBox.Name != "callNotes")
            textBox.SelectAll();
    }
```

Adding the **&& textBox.Name != "callNotes"** solved the problem.